# How to determine the reason for a full hard drive?

Tags: disk-usage, disk

My hard disk indicates that it is almost completely full, but when I check the files, I should have plenty of storage space left over.

I ran the command `df -h` and this is the result of one of the partitions:

```
Filesystem      Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on 
/dev/nvme0n1p5  110G    104G    363M    100%    /
```

But when I enter Disk Usage Analyzer, it tells me that I am only using 34.4 GB.

This came up after I ran the `sudo rm -r` command to delete a folder. I have already checked the Trash and it is empty.

Comment: What folder did you remove?

Comment: some other ways.... find cached files over a certain date
find ~/.cache/ -depth -type f -atime +365 
du ~/.cache | sort -n
delete them
find ~/.cache/ -type f -atime +365 -delete

ncdu show directory size